# How does SPSS MLP procedure choose the number of neurons in a hidden layer

Tags: neural-networks, spss

The SPSS MLP procedure can automatically choose the number of nodes in the hidden layer.  How does it choose this number?  How confident can I be that this number is anywhere near optimal?

Answer (score 0):

The method is not exactly simple. It's detailed in the Expert Architecture Selection section of the MLP algorithms in the IBM SPSS Statistics Algorithms manual, which is freely available as a pdf by searching online (you might get various versions, but anything relatively recent should contain this chapter).

In most cases the automatic selection should do a pretty good job, but there are no guarantees. If you really know what you're doing you can probably concoct an example where it doesn't perform very well.